# I forged a "right of wali" letter from my father and we lied to the imam about receiving mahr. Is our marriage valid?

Tags: nikah, wali, mehr

My husband and I lied to the imam so that we could get married. Also, I did not receive a mahr.  And I want to know if our marriage is valid or if we need to redo the nikah.  The details are as follows:

(1) When my husband approached my father to marry me, my father said he would consent if my husband agreed to show his passport and bank statements to confirm who he is and that he has money to support me.  My husband refused. So, my father said he would not act as my wali.  We asked an Imam to act as my wali instead and the imam said he would as long as I had a letter from my father agreeing to transfer his right of wali to the imam.  So, I wrote a letter myself and signed my father's name and gave it to the imam.  The imam married us because he thought the letter came from my father but it was a lie.

(2) My husband and I agreed on a mahr and we told the imam that I received it, but I did not. To this day, I still have not received a mahr.

Based on these two situations, is my marriage valid?

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. Please take your time to learn more about our site and model by taking our 2 min. [tour] and checking our [help]. Even if we assume your marriage is valid. You lied and committed many sins to get married... do you really think Allah would accept your union? Of course a marriage without mahr isn't valid neither is a marriage without the consent of a wali.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it requests a verdict on the validity of a marriage. The answer would depend on the school of thought followed by the questioner, and other details not mentioned in the question. Please consult a Qadi or Mufti for fatwas on your personal life. Otherwise reword the question to a more general query on Islamic laws.